# window.innerWidth can't work on IE7. How to fix via JS and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, internet-explorer-7

I wanna get the width of browser window. It should contain the width of scroll bar if exists.

How to fix this issue via JS?

How to fix this issue via jQuery?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many examples of this scattered around the web. It's a common problem. Here's what I found in a quick search

```
var winW = 630, winH = 460;
if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
 winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
 winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
}
if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
    document.documentElement &&
    document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
 winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
 winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
}
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
 winW = window.innerWidth;
 winH = window.innerHeight;
}
```

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there a jQuery solution? I use `$(window).innerWidth()`, but it's incorrect.

Comment: As far as I'm aware jQuery doesn't support a fix. innerWidth() is not valid for document or window objects. You are told to use .width() for these objects, but it doesn't include the scrollbars. The best you can do is use jQuery to detect the browser but you shouldn't do this to fix objects.

Answer (score 0):

this would fix using a jquery 
$(window).innerWidth();