# Transfer inline hard-coded jQuery function to variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, variables

I have the following code:

```
      <!-- work item 1 -->
      <li id="portfolio-1" class="col-12  col-sm-6  col-md-6  col-lg-4">
        <figure class="box  box--sm  text-center">
            <h4 class="brand--font-standard">Project Title</h4>
              <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-offset-2  col-xs-8  col-sm-offset-1  col-sm-10  col-md-offset-2  col-md-8  col-lg-offset-3  col-lg-6">
                  <img src="img/globe.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="globe">
                </div>
              </div>
            <figcaption>
              <p>Project comment</p>
              <a href="#" class="pull-right  brand--font" onclick="$('.work--detail').addClass('work--detail_show'); $('#work-2, #work-3, #work-4, #work-5, #work-6').hide(); $('#work-1').slideDown(); $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.hidden-content-top').offset().top - 110 }, 1000); return false;">View</a>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li><!-- /work item 1 -->
```

I'm wanting to rewrite the js on the anchor tag so that it is not hard-coded, instead having variables for the items that need to open/have .hide added to them.  There are currently 6 li's with ID's of #portfolio-(number) with corresponding hidden content for each with ID's of #work-(number).

The reason i'm wanting to do this is firstly to tidy the code up and make it a little more reusable.  But also, as the site is responsive I need to adjust the offset value based on the window width.

The corresponding hidden content would also need to work from variables as oppose to being hard-coded.  An example of this is:

```
<a href="#" class="btn  btn--small  btn--grey  brand--font" onclick="$('#work-1').slideUp(); $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#portfolio-1').offset().top - 140 }, 1000); $('.work--detail').removeClass('work--detail_show'); return false;">close</a>
```

Which I currently have the following function for (to get the window width):

```
var _getInnerWidth = function () {
return typeof window.innerWidth !== 'undefined' ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth;
```

Any help is appreciated!

[Demo is here](http://www.nerdswithhair.com/themes/uno)

PS - I can deal with the second part (adding the offset values based on the window width etc)

PPS - I'm a novice with js, so please be gentle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would add a little bit of clarity to the code:

```
var _getInnerWidth = function () {

    if(typeof window.innerWidth !== 'undefined'){
      innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    } else {
      innerWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    }

    return innerWidth;
}
```

Your code should work as is. I tried it and returned to me 1704.

I´m attaching a plunker here, with an example of something that I built based on the description of what you´re doing. Hope it helps

http://plnkr.co/edit/KXNGL089UIvfNlRmO2cC

Comment: You would be also interested on read this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563627/window-innerwidth-cant-work-on-ie7-how-to-fix-via-js-and-jquery

Comment: Also consider in having your function as a function declaration:

`function _getInnerWidth () {
//
}`

In this way you can be sure that you can call the function before is defined, if you try to call your function and it's a function expression:

`var _getInnerWidth = function () {
//
}`
and you call it before it´s defined it wont work.

Read this post too: Function Declarations vs Function Expressions:
http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Comment: Hi @Guillermo, appreciate your help with that.  But it's more the first part of the question I'm concerned about.

Comment: inside your function `$(this).attr('id')` will return the clicked li id, then you should apply some transform to the id -replace will work fine- and the with the original id apply the .hide, and with the new one aplly .show, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Try this inside your function:

`var receivedId = $(this).attr('id'),
     newId = receivedId.replace('portfolio','work');`

There you have the new and the "old" id, remember that if you are going to use them inside selectors, you should append the "#" to make it work.

Comment: Hi @Guillermo, sorry i'm confused (i'm only just learning js).  which part of the inline code would this replace?

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay. First thing you have to do to eliminate the obtrusive js (js inside the html) is to create a function, and then through a selector refer to that function.

for instance:

    `function myFunc() {
       //Your code here.....
    }`

Then refer to that function when your a is clicked.

    `$("#portfolio-1 a.pull-right").on("click", function (e) {
         e.preventDefault(); //This will prevent the link of its default behavior.

         //Then add all your "onclick" code here it should work.
    }`

Comment: Try that and tell me if you can get it working, if any error comes up, let me know. Once you have that it working we´ll do some adjustments to make that function work for every a, without hardcoding ids in the code. But as Jack said, let´s go by pieces.

Comment: Ok :) Not sure if this is right but this is what i've got so far: 
$("#portfolio-1 a.portfolio-toggle").click(function() { 
    $('.work--detail').addClass('work--detail_show'); 
    $('#work-2, #work-3, #work-4, #work-5, #work-6').hide(); 
    $('#work-1').slideDown(); 
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.hidden-content-top').offset().top - 110 }, 1000);
    return false;
});

Comment: You'll see that i've added .portfolio-toggle to the anchor tag

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've added a plunker to the answer with your function but refactored to be reusable. You will notice that just that function works for all your links, and your onClicks have disappeared.

Comment: That's fantatsic.  Is it also possible to perform the same code refactoring for the close sections of the code?  I'm guessing it would be something similar.  This is how it is at the moment:                      <a href="#" class="btn  btn--grey  brand--font" onclick="$('#work-1').slideUp(); $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#portfolio-1').offset().top - 140 }, 1000); $('.work--detail').removeClass('work--show'); return false;">close</a>

Comment: Hi @Guillermo.  Any thoughts on how to do the same for the close button?  Many thanks!

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the delay. Plunk updated. I put the code in the js. Take a look, you may catch the idea from there. I added some comments. If have questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks!! There was a small typo on one of the ID's.  It was down as   $(workId).slideUp();
...so i found it and changed it! (I'm learning!!)